# Where exactly is the border of an element drawn wrt to the margin and padding?

Tags: codenameone

In my css definition file, I've added css `borders` to many of the elements like containers in a list to separate them visually. However, the lines of the borders are sometimes not visible, or only partly visible.

I'm guessing it may be because the border's line is overwritten by the element next to it, so I'd like to understand exactly where CN1 draws the border. E.g. it is within the padding, just outside the padding, inside the margin or just outside the margin? Also, is the border *added* to the size of the padding or margin or is it drawn on top of either?

It seems like a pretty basic question, but I haven't been able to find the answer so far (e.g. borders are not shown in the diagram in section "Padding and Margin" here: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/theme-basics.html), so any help or pointer to the documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border is a part of the component so it falls within the padding. Notice this paragraph from the [theme basics](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/theme-basics.html) section:

> Padding and margin are concepts derived from the CSS box model. They
>   are slightly different in Codename One, where the border spacing is
>   part of the padding, but other than that they are pretty similar: ...

So effectively you need to make sure that there's enough padding to contain the border of the component. Margin resides outside of the component and the component is "unaware" of the margin.

If you think this isn't sufficiently clear or properly explained you can edit this to clarify it through the wiki page here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/wiki/Theme-Basics

The docs are generated from that page, see https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-edit-docs-fun-profit.html

Comment: Great, thanks for pointing this out. I’ve updated the text of the documentation with your answer. I’d probably also add it to the illustartion but don’t know how to edit that.

Comment: Thanks! I looked at this here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/wiki/Theme-Basics/_compare/98273000e17df0efdd7c0044d9d29a1952bbf982...579c5171e62c45228e5d4bd3e2986a7f18d3c277

What's `NB`? Also notice that my text is essentially the quote from line 217 just above the block you wrote so this is essentially written twice now. I think we can clarify this a bit more.

Comment: "NB" = Nota Bene (~ "take good notice that"). You're right, I didn't notice the text already preceding the illustration ("They are slightly different in Codename One, where the border spacing is part of the padding, but other than that they are pretty similar"). I think it is the wording of "border spacing" instead of "border" that wasn't totally clear to me. I reverted my edit. However, if you could update the illustration that would be worth a thousand words ;-)

Comment: It looks a bit noisy already and adding a border in there might be more confusing in other regards. I'll need to give this some thought.